# Change raster size GZ-File in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgz

I have Climate Data grids_germany_multi_annual_air_temp_mean_1981-2010_17.asc.gz from the ftp-server of the Deutsche Wetterdienst as raster files of multi-annual mean temperature.

Source:

https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/multi_annual/air_temperature_mean/

[image]

After unzipping, I want to change the size of the raster in QGIS. I'm aware that the smaller rasters will have the same value as the original ones. But I'll need a higher resolution for clipping later on.

I tried several things, but I can't figure out how to change the raster size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Raster - Projections - Warp.

My original raster has a pixel size of 50 m which I resample to 20 m with:

[image]